# C# system out of memory exception when trying to merge mutiple json

Tags: c#, json

We receive many json documents from different client applications. These json documents are pretty sizeable. I'm working on creating a process to consolidate all of this data. As part of this routine I'm using C# to merge all of these documents. But, when I do so I run into the below error. I tried using streaming approach to read and merge the JSON data without loading entire content into memory and still run into this out of memory error.

***Error:*** `Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.`

***C#***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.IO;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string directoryPath = @"C:\test\Directory";
        string outputPath = @"C:\test\cons.json";
        List<JToken> jsonTokens = new List<JToken>();

        try
        {
            string[] jsonFiles = Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath, "*.json");
            foreach (string jsonFile in jsonFiles)
            {
                using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StreamReader(jsonFile)))
                {
                    JToken jsonToken = JToken.ReadFrom(reader);
                    jsonTokens.Add(jsonToken);
                }
            }
            JToken mergedToken = jsonTokens.Count > 1 ? new JArray(jsonTokens) : jsonTokens[0];
            File.WriteAllText(outputPath, mergedToken.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(error.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

What options do I have to work around this memory issue?

Comment: How big are your files? And are you running in 64 bit mode?

Comment: It varies from day to day. I would say it would be safe to assume it's over 2 gb a day. Yes, running it in 64 bit mode.

Comment: even though you're using streams, the entire files are still being loaded as jtokens into memory. And jtokens might actually take up more memory than the strings themselves.

Comment: Not only that, but the result is converted to an intermediate string with `File.WriteAllText(outputPath, mergedToken.ToString());` instead of being written to a stream directly.

Comment: Can you share the structure of the JSON files?

Comment: Maybe JSON isn't the best option. You can do something like putting the JSON data into an actual database (ex MySql), which is built to handle large amounts of data.

Comment: How many files are you expecting to have inside the directory?

Comment: I will have atleast 20 files in the directory. I need to merge them even before I can write them to a database.

Comment: Judging from your code, that's not really a merge, that's a concatenation. Can't you write them to the database directly? Why is that concatenation required?

Comment: Even after sorting this out, you might encounter a similar challenge on the other side, especially if you're working with a hefty 40GB JSON file.

Comment: Consider using [JSON Lines](https://jsonlines.org/)

Answer (score 1):

I see you're trying to concatenate files without merging. Here's a quick solution that might help you create a large JSON file with all the others in an array:

```cs
await using var outputFile = new FileStream("output.json", FileMode.Create);
var strings = Directory.GetFiles("jsons");
var first = true;
await outputFile.WriteAsync("[\n"u8.ToArray(), 0, 1);
foreach (var s in strings)
{
    if (!first)
    {
        await outputFile.WriteAsync(",\n"u8.ToArray(), 0, 2);
    }

    first = false;
    await using var readAllBytesAsync = new FileStream(s, FileMode.Open);
    await readAllBytesAsync.CopyToAsync(outputFile);
    await outputFile.FlushAsync();
}
await outputFile.WriteAsync("\n]"u8.ToArray(), 0, 1);
```

However, I'd recommend taking a moment to reconsider. Using something like MongoDB might be more efficient. Creating a huge JSON file means the receiving end will need a lot of memory to process it (e.g., 80GB of memory for a 40GB JSON file [40GB for the file itself and 40gb for the parsed version of it]). It'd be great to explore better data transmission and processing methods. Learning new approaches can be beneficial. Using file exchanges in a directory as an API interface might not be the best architectural choice.